# Drupal 7 form state undefined index

Tags: drupal

I create a form like this in .module file:

```
function form_registration_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form['registration']['email'] = array(
'#title' => t('EMAIL ADDRESS'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 44,
    '#maxlength' => '80',
    '#rules' => array(
        'email', 
        'length[10, 50]',
    )
  );
  $form['registration']['password'] = array(
    '#title' => t('PASSWORD'),
    '#type' => 'password',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 44,
    '#maxlength' => '80',
  );
  $form['registration']['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'SIGN IN',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#submit' => array('form_registration_handler')
    );
  return $form;
}
function form_registration_handler($form, &$form_state){
    $email = $form_state['registration']['email'];
        drupal_set_message($email);
}
```

However drupal always say that  "Undefined index: registration in form_registration_form_submit()". I really dont know what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestions will be very useful for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok I figure out what I am doing wrong here. Just change the code like this:

function form_registration_handler($form, &$form_state){
    $email = $form_state['values']['email'];
    drupal_set_message($email);
}
Evething works smoothly :D

Answer (score 1):

You can always enable the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and dsm($form) the submit function. For instance:

```
function form_registration_handler($form, &$form_state){
    dsm($form);
    dsm($form_state);
}
```

By DSMing, you can easily find the value you want to use in your submit function.

Comment: Yeah I use the Form API modules and it has the '#rules' like this in Drupal Form. Anw, thank for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to head of your form_registration_form function:

```
$form = array();
$form['registration'] = array();
```

The notice appear becuse $form['registration'] is not declared as a void array.